# .obj file is not loading all the child mesh name

Tags: xcode, scenekit

Here, I am using SceneKit with .obj model. I need some help to get parts / submesh name with the SceneKit.ModelIO.

Is it possible to get all meshes name of .obj ? Please check below code.

```
     // Here Obj url
    let url = "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/p9-platform/DAE/barware_s11624.obj"    
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: url as URL)
    let scene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: asset)
    let mesh = asset.object(at:0) as! MDLMesh
    let vertexBuffer = mesh.vertexBuffers[0]
    let descripter = mesh.vertexDescriptor
    let submeshes = mesh.submeshes

    for index in 0...(submeshes?.count)! - 1{

     let submesh0 = submeshes![index] as! MDLSubmesh

     let singleMesh = MDLMesh(vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer, vertexCount: mesh.vertexCount, descriptor: descripter, submeshes:  [submesh0])

     let geometry = SCNGeometry(mdlMesh: singleMesh)

     let Node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

     scene.rootNode.addChildNode(Node)
   }
   print("scene ===>\(scene.rootNode)")  

   //Print scene Result in Xcode console               
   scene ===><SCNNode: 0x1c41ef300 | 7 children>

   print("object.childNodes==>\(object.childNodes)")

   //Print object.childNodes Result
```

This is the output in Xcode console.

```
object.childNodes==>[<SCNNode: 0x1c41e9300 'default' | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c5339280 'default' | 6 elements> | no child>, <SCNNode: 0x1c41f5a00 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c5339320 'Obj1'> | no child>, <SCNNode: 0x1c41f5b00 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c53393c0 'Obj2'> | no child>, <SCNNode: 0x1c41f5d00 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c5339460 'Obj3'> | no child>, <SCNNode: 0x1c41f5e00 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c5339500 'Obj4'> | no child>, <SCNNode: 0x1c41f5f00 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c53395a0 'Obj5'> | no child>, <SCNNode: 0x1c01f3c00 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x1c0522260 'Obj6'> | no child>]
```

I want same output this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441162/convert-obj-fbx-to-dae-runtime-which-must-support-ios-scenekit/48923737#48923737), my recommendation is to use Assimp to load the files, it should load all the data and gives you much more control over how to process it.